# docker-compose cannot resolve DNS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dns, dockerfile

The problem is that docker compose cannot build image, failing on `RUN npm ci`. But after hours of debugging, I isolated the problem and pinned it in this minimal setup:

My `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  myapp:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
      target: development
    command: sleep Infinity
```

My `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS development
RUN ping google.com
```

When I run `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --build`
I'm getting error:[image]

### What I tried so far

1. In Dockerfile replace `ping google.com` to `ping <real-ip>`. ✅ And it works, so I assume it's DNS problem.
2. Add `dns` into docker-compose.yml: `dns: 8.8.8.8`. ❌ No luck
3. Run under super user `sudo docker compose …`. ❌ No luck
4. I tried to build image from Dockerfile without compose, using just `docker build` command. ✅ And it works, so the problem with `docker compose`.
5. Commented `RUN ping …` command, so it does not fail and runs `sleep Infinity` form the compose config. Then I connected into the container via `docker exec -it <container> sh` and was able to ping google and run `npm ci`. So when container is running it has access to DNS. **The problem happens only in docker compose on the build stage from Dockerfile**.

#### Environment

It's a VPS on hetzner. I ssh under a user with `sudo` and `docker` group.